# How to fix uncaught javaScript referenceError?

Tags: javascript

Uncaught ReferenceError: displayTodos is not defined
    at :1:1

```js
var todoList = {
  todos: [],
  displayTodos: function() {
    if (this.todos.length === 0) {
      console.log('You have nothing todo!');
    } else {
      console.log('My Todos:');
      for (var i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.todos[i].todoText);
      }
    }
  },
  addTodo: function(todoText) {
    this.todos.push({
      todoText: todoText,
      completed: false
    });
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  changeTodo: function(position, todoText) {
    this.todos[position].todoText = todoText;
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  deleteTodo: function(position) {
    this.todos.splice(position, 1);
    this.displayTodos();
  },
  toggleCompleted: function(position) {
    var todo = this.todos[position];
    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
    this.displayTodos();
  }
};
```

expected displayTodos(); to display to do list, but am receiving the error above.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Same, I have run this code successfully. Recommend you look at surrounding code for a syntax error.

Comment: Please include the code that you are using to call into the object.

Comment: Is this Sencha code or using some other ui Framework? You have to show how you use this object. This does not necessarily refer to the object when passing a function as a parameter to a different function

Comment: todos isn't a variable, it's a property of the todoList object.  You access it with todoList.displayTodos().

Comment: displayTodos();

Comment: displayTodos();

Comment: You can't just call `displayTodos()`. It is a member of `todoList`. You'd have to call `todoList.displayTodos()`.

Comment: thank you @ Scott Marcus.  It is a rookie mistake.  I will be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `displayTodos()` function is not defined in global scope, you need to use this instead:

`todoList.displayTodos();`

Comment: :) good call, I think we all assume people know this. Could well be the error.

Comment: when I was working as a director of technology in a pretty big company, I've learned to not to assume that people don't make basic mistakes :)